# Merge Javascript Function with Ajax Post

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have little knowledge about Javascript and ajax, I have below javascript function which is basicaly a time based progressbar

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function progress(timeleft, timetotal, $element) {
var n = document.getElementById("validating");    
var x = document.getElementById("progressBar");
var y = document.getElementById("success-bar");
var z=  document.getElementById("error-bar");
var foobarElement = document.getElementById('foobar'); 
foobarElement.style.backgroundImage = ''; //Removing background gear img from iframe
x.style.display = "block";
var progressBarWidth = timeleft * $element.width() / timetotal;
$element.find('div').animate({ width: progressBarWidth }, 3000).html(timeleft + " seconds to go");
if(timeleft > 0) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        progress(timeleft - 1, timetotal, $element);
    }, 1000);
} else{   
   x.style.display = "none";
   n.style.display = "none";
   y.style.display = "block";
   z.style.display = "block";
   }   
};
```

I am trying to include below ajax postback function in above `else` spot but it is not working,how can I include below ajax in above javascript else spot

```
 $.ajax({
     url:"/post_back2222.php",
     type:"POST",
     data:{file: include},
     success: function(){
          // you can get executed content of a file here. 
          alert("Hello! I am an alert box!!");
     }
});
```

Comment: Not happening mean what ? What is the error you are seeing?

Comment: no error it is showing not printing the alert too

Comment: is the code going inside else block?

Comment: Wrap ajax in a function (ex. `function initAjax() {`All ajax code here`}`) then place `initAjax()` in the `else` block.